# Facebook apps being redirected to 404 page

Tags: facebook, iframe, redirect, http-status-code-404

Following a server move last week I have found that all the Facebook iframe apps I host are being redirect to http://www.facebook.com/4oh4.php

This is a straight redirection from the apps.facebook.com URL to the facebook 404 page - using httpFox. I can't see any request going to my server at all.

The funny thing is everything works fine when I'm using the app admin account on my PC.

I've check and the apps aren't in sandbox mode. It must be something to do with the server move. This was just a DNS update I didn't need to change any of the app settings.

Has anyone else seen anything like this before?

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: +1 just for being named Billy Mays.

Comment: Why thank you :-) To add to my original post: I am using the PHP API, I have been able to narrow the problem down to be something to do with the user's accounts - tried running my app on another server it made no difference, had one of the users experiencing the problem try on another machine, it made no difference. Had the same user create a new account and try again - it worked. Occasionally the user gets the error "An error occurred with <app name>, please try again later", after granting permission to the app, so I think the problem might be authentication related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually an indication that your app is in "Sandbox"/dev mode.  You need to take it out of Sandbox:

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Select your app and click "Edit Settings"
3. On the left hand side menu, under Settings, click "Advanced"
4. Under Sandbox mode, click "Disabled"
5. Scroll to the bottom and click "Save changes".

Comment: The user is already suggesting that the app is not in Sandbox mode.